# "Sync is Off" showing after running the Sync Adapter On Demand using ContentResolver.requestSync() function

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I am trying to implement Contact Sync Adapter. Its working fine when I do sync operation from the sync option given under corresponding Account. But when I try to call `requestSync()` **first time** on button click, `onPerformSync()` function of SyncAdapter implementation called and executed successfully but still showing **Sync is Off** under corresponding Account in Sync Settings.

My code for Running Sync adapter on demand is :

```
Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();
                settingsBundle.putBoolean(
                        ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
                settingsBundle.putBoolean(
                        ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
                /*
                 * Request the sync for the default account, authority, and
                 * manual sync settings
                 */


                ContentResolver.requestSync(mAccount, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);
```

So please guide me, is there any way to turn on Sync Setting after running the Sync Adapter On Demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to set below property before calling `requestSync(----)` for achieve my goal :

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(mAccount, getString(R.string.content_provider_authority), true);
```

Comment: Somewhat corresponding: I expected that calling ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, authority, bundle, internalSecs) will set up my sync adapter as turned on but that's not the case. Calling setSyncAutomatically solved my problem as well.